# complex query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pivot

Hello and warm greetings to you all,
I am having some challenges writing a complex query in posgresql. the fact is i'm having problem writing this particular query period, and your help is kindly needed. lets get to it.

here are my tables

```
[products_tb]         [client_tb]          [sales_tb]
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+--------------+-----+
| product_name |      | client_name |      | client_name | product_name | qty | 
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+--------------+-----+
| shoe         |      | john        |      | john        | shoe         | 20  |
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+--------------+-----+
| belt         |      | bob         |      | john        | belt         | 9   |
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+--------------+-----+
                      | kim         |      | bob         | shoe         | 2   |
                      +-------------+      +-------------+--------------+-----+
                                           | bob         | belt         | 98  |
                                           +-------------+--------------+-----+
                                           | kim         | shoe         | 46  |
                                           +-------------+--------------+-----+
                                           | kim         | belt         | 3   |
                                           +-------------+--------------+-----+


[query output] # this output will be displayed using php and html
+----------+-------+------+-----+-----+
| products | Total | john | bob | kim |
+----------+-------+------+-----+-----+
| shoe     | 68    | 20   | 2   | 46  |
+----------+-------+------+-----+-----+
| belt     | 110   | 9    | 98  | 3   |
+----------+-------+------+-----+-----+
```

I am trying to write a query which will allow me to produce the table [query output]. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is called "pivot" (search for it, this is being asked on a weekly basis here). Check out the `crosstab()` function in the `tablefunc` module:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Please always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions. What have you tried?

Comment: @Craig: sorry, i'm using PostgresSQL 9.2. I am currenty reading about pivot and table functions which were suggested earlier. I'm yet to give it a try

Comment: Although there is the `tablefunc` module as suggested by @a_horse I find it easier to dynamically build the query in the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A version without using cross_tab:

```
select p.product_name, sum(s.qty), 
sum(CASE WHEN c.client_name='john' THEN s.qty END) as john,
sum(CASE WHEN c.client_name='bob' THEN s.qty END) as bob,
sum(CASE WHEN c.client_name='kim' THEN s.qty END) as kim
   from products_tb AS p 
   JOIN sales_tb AS s ON p.product_name=s.product_name
   JOIN clients_tb AS c ON c.client_name=s.client_name
   GROUP BY p.product_name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/afc9a/10

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, however, i'm looking for a more dynamic solution since the client_name will be a lot and different clients.

Comment: would it be efficient if i wrote a first query to get DISTINCT client_names and loop through and echo the sum(CASE WHEN c.client_name="loop_val") as loop_val?

Comment: @Govnah Yes it would. Such a thing should be done in a client where it's much easier so if you want it to be efficient you shouldn't deal with it in the db.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was insightful, i usually deal with minor database setup and simple queries. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it using standard SQL:

```
SELECT st.product_name AS products,
       SUM(st.qty) AS Total,
       (SELECT SUM(st_john.qty)
        FROM sales_tb st_john
        WHERE client_name = 'john' AND st_john.product_name = st.product_name) AS john,
       (SELECT SUM(st_bob.qty)
        FROM sales_tb st_bob
        WHERE client_name = 'bob' AND st_bob.product_name = st.product_name) AS bob,
       (SELECT SUM(st_kim.qty)
        FROM sales_tb st_kim
        WHERE client_name = 'kim' AND st_kim.product_name = st.product_name) AS kim
FROM sales_tb st
GROUP BY product_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2e3bd/4)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, its a great start and pointing me to the right direction. problem i might have with this solution is that, the client names are going to grow and possibly dynamic. i am not sure how i will convert your solution to a dynamic one.

Comment: If the client_names are dynamic then I'd suggest having them as rows rather than columns in your results table...